# Is padding only included in a view size if its set to wrap content?

Tags: android, css, xml, kotlin

In this example, there will be no text shown as it is covered by padding.

```
<TextView
     android:padding="250px"
     android:layout_width="500px"
     android:layout_height="500px"
     android:background="@color/yellow"
     android:text="some text"
     android:textColor="@color/red"/>
```

however, in this example the padding will be added onto the sizes thus there will be a larger textview and visible text.

```
<TextView
      android:padding="250px"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@color/yellow"
      android:text="some text"
      android:textColor="@color/red"/>
```

**Is there a way in pure xml to set an arbitrary width and/or height and have the view size include the padding just like with html?**

Answer (score 1):

Just decide on a certain size and add the paddings onto it.

```
<----------------- 1000px ---------------->
<-- 250px --><---- 500px ----><-- 250px -->
```

Otherwise you can still use a margin.